# I have been working on trying to create a Simon Say game specific trying to work out some bugs when using Graphics 2D

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

For some reason `Graphics2D` won't generate the background I am trying to set. I think the problem is something to do with renderer sending the information back to Simon the main class. I can't seem to find a solution and have been looking for hours online. If anyone know graphics 2D well or sees the issue with the code and can help that would be greatly appreciated.

```
package Simon;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestingSimon implements ActionListener {

    //Creating object simon
    public static TestingSimon simon;
    //Making integers for Width and Height for JFrame
    public static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;
    //making a renderer for graphics2D
    public Renderer renderer;

    public TestingSimon() {
        //Creating JFrame 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simon Says");
        //using animation for a timer
        Timer timer = new Timer(20,this);

        //assigning renderer to the method I create in java class Renderer
        renderer = new Renderer();

        //setting a size for the JFrame
        frame.setSize(WIDTH + 15, HEIGHT + 35);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(renderer);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        timer.start();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        simon = new TestingSimon();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //setting it to repaint when action event occurs
        renderer.repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        //trying to set background to grey using Graphics2D
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
}
```

---

```
//Java package Renderer
package Simon;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


/**
 *
 * @author chasepflueger
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
//extending JPanel
public class Renderer extends JPanel
{

    /**
     *
     * @param g
     */
    //trying to implement paintComponent to Simon
    @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g);

       if(TestingSimon.simon != null)
       {
       TestingSimon.simon.paint((Graphics2D) g);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your structure seems a bit messed up. `Simon` has a `Frame`. The `Frame` has a `Renderer`. The `Renderer` calls back `Simon`. Why? If you want `Simon` to be drawable, then make it extend `JFrame`, `JPanel`, or whatever, and add it to a container. If you want to separate logic from drawing, then don't let `Simon` have anything to do with UI.

Answer (score 0):

> //trying to set background to grey using Graphics2D

Painting the background of a component is already support by all Swing components. All you do is set the background Color:

```
renderer = new Renderer();
renderer.setBackground(Color.GREY); // also try Color.RED to see the difference
```

Painting is a function of Java components:

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    //trying to set background to grey using Graphics2D
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
}
```

You can't just add a method to any class and expect painting to work. Your `TestingSimon` class is not a Component so that does nothing. Get rid of the code.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working example you can download and play with to learn the basics.